# Cardinality: Equality between |P(A)^B| and |P(B)^A|.

Tags: functions, cardinals

Let A and B be sets.

Show, that $|(P(A))^B|=|(P(B))^A|$.
I've tried to construct a bijection between the two, but so far I have failed miserably.

I would appreciate any tip that might push me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $P(A)\sim 2^A$ so $P(A)^B \sim (2^A)^B$

Comment: The sets might be infinite though :/

Comment: This is still true

Comment: Oh thats neat then :) Thank you kind stranger